# Add dynamic action to $resource

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to make one of the $resource actions(e.g. isArray or cache) dynamic?

HTML

```
terminalsResource.findTerminals({cached: true}, function (data) {
                        $scope.terminals = data;
                    }, function (response) {
```

JS

```
//Where to add dynamic properties?
    return $resource("rest/terminals", {useCache:'@cached'}, {
        /**
         * @method findTerminals
         * Find all terminals
         * @return {Array} Terminals
         */
        findTerminals: { method: "GET", isArray: true, cache: useCache}

    });
```

Above code doesn't work, but it shapes an image of what I wan't to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Specifically to cache:** I would say your code should work as `cache` is a supported property for your GET action. It expects a boolean or a cache instance build with `$cacheFactory`.

> http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource
>
> **cache** – {boolean|Cache} – If true, a default $http cache will be used to cache the GET request, otherwise if a cache instance built with $cacheFactory, this cache will be used for caching.

The only thing that I can think of why your code does not work is, that the given boolean via `{useCache:'@cached'}` is not taken out at the right time to use it as for action.cache.

---

This way it should definitely work as you are constructing `$resource` at the time you call your specific service factory function. Did **not** test this, but should show the idea.

```
.factory('Terminal', function($resource){
  var Terminal = {};
  
  Terminal.findTerminals = function(params, useCache) {
    return $resource("rest/terminals", params, {
      /**
       * @method findTerminals
       * Find all terminals
       * @return {Array} Terminals
       */
      findTerminals: { method: "GET", isArray: true, cache: useCache}
    });
  }
  
  return Terminal;
});
```

And then:

```
Terminal.findTerminals({}, true, function (data) {
  $scope.terminals = data;
}, function (response) {
```

Comment: Yes this is the only working way so far. My "solution"; I just added 2 methods in the resource: findTerminalsCache and findTerminalsNoCache